# Rename Dexterity object (id) after copy

Tags: plone, dexterity

It's simple to choose the object ID at creation time with `INameChooser`.
But we also want to be able to choose the object ID after a clone (and avoid `copy_of` in object ID).

We tried several different solutions :

- subscribers on events :

  - `OFS.interfaces.IObjectClonedEvent`
  - `zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent`
  - ...
- `manage_afterClone` method on content class

Every time, we get a traceback because we changed the ID "too soon". For example when using Plone API :

```
  File "/Users/laurent/.buildout/eggs/plone.api-2.0.0a1-py3.7.egg/plone/api/content.py", line 256, in copy
    return target[new_id]
  File "/Users/laurent/.buildout/eggs/plone.folder-3.0.3-py3.7.egg/plone/folder/ordered.py", line 241, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'copy_of_87c7f9b7e7924d039b832d3796e7b5a3'
```

Or, with a Copy / Paste in the Plone instance :

```
  Module plone.app.content.browser.contents.paste, line 42, in __call__
  Module OFS.CopySupport, line 317, in manage_pasteObjects
  Module OFS.CopySupport, line 229, in _pasteObjects
  Module plone.folder.ordered, line 73, in _getOb
AttributeError: 'copy_of_a7ed3d678f2643bc990309cde61a6bc5'
```

It's logical, because the ID is stored before events notification / `manage_afterClone` call for later use.

Even defining a `_get_id` on containers cannot work to define the ID, because we don't have the object to get attributes from (and generate the ID).

But then, how could we achieve this in a clean way ?
Please tell me there is a better solution than redefining `_pasteObjects` (`OFS.CopySupport`) !

Thank you for your inputs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unfortunately not...

But you can access the original object from within `_get_id`.

For example:

```py
from OFS.CopySupport import _cb_decode
from plone import api

    ...
    def _get_id(self, id_):
        # copy_or_move => 0 means copy, 1 means move
        copy_or_move, path_segments = _cb_decode(self.REQUEST['__cp']
        source_path = '/'.join(path_segments[0])  # Imlement for loop for more than one copied obj.
        app = self.getPhysicalRoot()

        # access to source obj
        source_obj = app.restrictedTraverse(source_path)
        # Do whatever you need - probably using INameChooser
    ....
```

To have a canonical way of patching this I use [collective.monkeypatcher](https://pypi.org/project/collective.monkeypatcher/)

Once installed add the following in ZCML:

```
  <include package="collective.monkeypatcher" />

  <monkey:patch
      class="OFS.CopySupport.CopyContainer"
      original="_get_id"
      replacement="patches.patched_get_id"
      />
```

Where `patches.py` is your module containing the new method `patched_get_id`, which replaces `_get_id`.

I'm sorry I don't have better news for you, but this is how I solved a similar requirement.

This code (`patched _get_id`) adds a counter at the end of a id if already there.

```
def patched_get_id(self, id_)
    match = re.match('^(.*)-([\d]+)$', id_)
    if match:
        id_ = match.group(1)
        number = int(match.group(2))
    else:
        number = 1
    
    new_id = id_
    while new_id in self.objectIds():
        new_id = '{}-{}'.format(id_, number)
        number += 1
    return new_id
```